# More than 100 certificates for a GKE loadbalancer?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

We have an app that allows clients to map their custom domains. We want to use GKE for the infra.

A quick look at the Google Managed Certificates, states that the maximum number of certificates is 100.

We want to **support more than 100** `clien-n.com` domains, and need to forward client requests to our app that sits behind the load balancer.

What are our options?

Comment: This is a Google support question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to request a quota request. You can go to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/contact) reach the sales team and request to increase the 100 limit for Google managed certificate.

You can also request this in your console. Follow the steps below.

1. Go to IAM & Admin
2. Look and click Quota & System Limits
3. Beside "Filter", type Certificate Manager
4. Click "Certificate Manager API" Beside "Managed Certificate"
5. Click the check box of the Managed Certificate then click "Edit Quotas"
6. From Edit quotas, fill out information.
7. Then "Submit Request"

If this option is not available in your console, I suggest you reach sales team to ask guidance how you can request to increase the limit of Google Managed Certificate.

If you dont like the option of increasing the quota limit of your Google Managed Certificate, you can also use self managed certificate option in your load balancer.